# Construction of Square Equal to Given Polygon.

Tags: geometry, measure-theory

Suppose that I have some polygon, I want to show that with "finite straight line cuts" I can get a square which is equal to that polygon.
Is there an algebraic proof for that?

Thank you.

Comment: Ur question is not clear to me

Comment: equal to that square in which sense

Comment: Sounds like you are talking about equidecomposability. The relevant theorem is here: [Wallace–Bolyai–Gerwien](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallace%E2%80%93Bolyai%E2%80%93Gerwien_theorem) although I would encourage you to try to prove it for yourself, it's really a gem.

Answer (score 0):

[I hope the following meets the requirement of “finite straight line cuts”. Also the proof is geometrical instead.]

[image]

Let ABCDEFGH…. be an n-sided polygon.

Construction:- (1) After joining DB, draw a line, through C, parallel to DB cutting AB extended at C’. (2) Join DC’ and let it cut CB at X.

By “equal base and equal altitude”, [⊿DCX] = [⊿BXC’]

∴ [polygon ABCDE….] = [polygon ABCDE….] – [⊿DCX] + [⊿BXC’] = [polygon A(B)C’(X)DE….]

In other words, the original n-sided polygon is reduced to an (n – 1)-sided polygon having the same area.

Repeating the process, we will arrive at a triangle having the same area of the original polygon.

It is now a simple matter to turn a triangle into a square having the same area. See http://www.contracosta.edu/legacycontent/math/TriangleToSquare.htm (and follow the instructions).